# OutgoingWebResponseContext does not display non-english characters

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, rest

We have implmented a REST-style get service Using WCF in .Net 3.5. This service retrieves research documents. The string 'synopsis' indicated in the code bolow contains non-english characteres which the browser deliveres as "????????".

private void ReturnSynopsisInfo(IApiWebOperationContext context, OutgoingWebResponseContext outgoingResp, string synopsis)
        {
            SetResponseHeaders(outgoingResp, HttpStatusCode.OK);
            outgoingResp.ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
            context.Result = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(synopsis));
        }

Any advise is much appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are declaring the encoding as utf-8 in the content-type header, but actually using ASCII encoding in stream. The ASCII encoder will silently change any non-ascii character into a question mark.

You probably want to use `UTF8Encoding` rater than `ASCIIEncoding`.

Comment: you are 100% correct. don't know how i missed. thank you very much